# properties.store(FileOutputStream,comments) is escaping my special character while writting

Tags: java, file, properties, properties-file

Is there is any way to not escape special characters being written in file?
For example String

> jdbc:postgresql://10.12.73.11:5432/dbname

is getting written in a file as

> jdbc:postgresql://10.12.73.11:5432/dbname

Here character ":" is getting escaped. Is there any way to write string as it is?
please refer the code sample below.

```
properties.put("spring.datasource.url", "jdbc:postgresql://10.12.73.11:5432/pomdb");
File file = new File("C:\\\\config/test.properties");
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, false));
properties.store(outputStreamWriter,"test_comments");
```

I have also checked out the code for properties.store(). Seems to be no option is given to exclude this escaping of special characters.
Help me with this if anyone knows workaround solution apart from writing your own store method or related logic to do the same task.
Also let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: *Is there is any way to not escape special characters being written in file* Why you need this? If you read the properties it will be unescaped

Comment: @Jens Yes. But there are some scenarios where some scripts other than java and third party systems might access it. which I need to handle at my side :)

Comment: The escaping will be done by the private method saveConvert. So you can overwite this method and all that call this method